# Android sms UDH specification?

Tags: android, sms, concatenation

We know that android doesn't allow to send messages which are longer than 160 symbols.

I want to use UDH in order to read the meta-information about each sms such as number of messages in the sequence and index of this message in order to decide whether I should or should not concatenate it with the previous ones.

So is there any specification for android sms UDH or if it's not specific for just android, is there any common UDH specs where I can find how to retrieve this information?

Comment: Hi, did you found a way to set the UDH on android?

Answer (score 0):

UDH is part of the SMS-spec so it is not specific for Android at all. Wikipedia has some information about this subject:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenated_SMS